# Mysql error, database:

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a php script while making entries to database through the script admin suddent I got this error, can anybody guide me how can I fix it?

```
Duplicate entry '140237' for key 'PRIMARY'INSERT INTO xzclf_cities SET cityname = 'Chrmouth', countryid = 874, enabled = '1
```

Comment: The error is self-explaining. You tried to insert duplicate record. You shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

It means your primary key already exists.

Make sure what your primary key of this table is. Probably it's the **cityid**. If this is the case you are trying to insert a new row with cityname **Chrmouth** for a cityid that is already existing.

If **cityname** is your primary key, then a record already exists with this cityname.

Remember that a [primary key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) should be unique!!

Answer (score 0):

The entry 140237 is repeating in a column that was labelled a primary key.A primary key column allows no duplicate entries.

Comment: Well I'm using a script and everything was alright I haved added many entries without problem but suddenly this issue occured. How can i fix it to allow me more entries?

Comment: you must have entered a value that is already in the column.If thats is necessary,remove the primary key tag from the column,using
    
    ALTER TABLE MODIFY col_name col_definition